# Aborting worker object in QThread

Tags: qt5, wait, qthread, worker, qt5.5

I know that there are many posts on this topic and i've read them and thought i also understood them. But I am still having a problem with aborting a QThread or rather a worker object in a QThread.

I have an GUI application and a library. The GUI can request the library to exec and abort worker objects (is connected to WorkerHandler slots). The WorkerHandler can create several WorkerObjects that all inherit from a base class. I tried to reduce the code for this example, but it's still some kind of verbose.

**Gui.h**

```
class Gui : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Gui(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Gui();
private:

    Ui::GuiClass ui;
    QThread *workerHandlerThread;
    WorkerHandler *workerHandler;
    void connectActions();

signals:
    void execWorker(WorkerParams _params);
    void abortWorker(WorkerType type);

slots:
    void buttonExecPressed();
    void buttonAbortPressed();
}
```

**Gui.cpp**

```
void Gui::Gui()
{   
    ui.btnExecA->setProperty("type", QVariant::fromValue(WorkerType::A)); //WorkerType is just a enum, bin type to button
    ui.btnExecB->setProperty("type", QVariant::fromValue(WorkerType::B));
    ui.btnAbortA->setProperty("type", QVariant::fromValue(WorkerType::A));
    ui.btnAbortB->setProperty("type", QVariant::fromValue(WorkerType::B));
    connectActions();

    workerHandlerThread = new QThread();
    workerHandler = new WorkerHandler();
    workerHandler->moveToThread(workerHandlerThread); // move worker execution to another thread
    workerHandlerThread->start(); //start will call run and run will run the QEventLoop of QThread by calling exec
}

void Gui::~Gui()
{   
    workerHandlerThread->quit();
    workerHandlerThread->wait();
    delete workerHandlerThread;
    delete workerHandler;
}

void Gui::connectActions()
{
    connect(ui.btnExecA, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Gui::buttonExecPressed);
    connect(ui.btnExecB, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Gui::buttonExecPressed);
    connect(ui.btnAbortA, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Gui::buttonAbortPressed);
    connect(ui.btnAbortB, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Gui::buttonAbortPressed);   
    connect(this, &Gui::execWorker, workerHandler, &WorkerHandler::execWorker);
    connect(this, &Gui::abortWorker, workerHandler, &WorkerHandler::abortWorker);
}

void Gui::buttonExecPressed()
{
    QPushButton* button = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
    if (button)
    {
        WorkerType type = button->property("type").value<WorkerType>(); //get worker type
        WorkerParams params = WorkerParamsFactory::Get()->CreateParams(type); //WorkerParamsFactory cretes default parameters based on type
        emit execWorker(params); //tell WorkerHandler to create a workerObject based on these parameters
    }
}

void Gui::buttonAbortPressed()
{
    QPushButton* button = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
    if (button)
    {
        WorkerType type = button->property("type").value<WorkerType>(); 
        emit abortWorker(type); //tell WorkerHandler to abort a specific workerObject
    }
}
```

**WorkerHandler.h**

```
class WorkerHandler : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    WorkerHandler(QObject * parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~WorkerHandler();


public slots:
    void execWorker(WorkerParams _params);
    void abortWorker(WorkerType type);

private:
    QMap<WorkerType, WorkerObjectBase*> workerPool; //contains the workerobjects
};
```

**WorkerHandler.cpp**

```
void WorkerHandler::execWorker(WorkerParams _params)
{

    QThread *thread = new QThread();
    WorkerObjectBase *worker = WorkerObjectFactory::Get()->CreateWorker(_params);  //Factory to create specific Worker Object based on given params
    worker->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(thread, &QThread::started, workerThread, &WorkerObjectBase::process); 
    connect(workerThread, &WorkerObjectBase::workerFinished, thread, &QThread::quit);  //quit the QThread when worker is finished
    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QThread::deleteLater); //free resources when thread is finished
    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, workerThread, &WorkerObjectBase::deleteLater);  //free resources when thread is finished

    workerPool.insert(_params.type, worker); //_params.type contains WorkerType

    thread->start(); //will call run of qthread which will call exec
}


void WorkerHandler::abortWorker(WorkerType type)
{
    WorkerObjectBase *worker = workerPool.value(type);
    worker->requestAbort();

    QThread *workerThread = worker->thread();

    if (workerThread)
    {
        if (!workerThread->wait(10000)) //will always block the 10 seconds and terminate the thread. using just wait() will block forever
        {
            workerThread->terminate();
        }
    }
}
```

**WorkerHandlerBase.h**

```
class WorkerObjectBase : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    WorkerObjectBase(QObject * parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~WorkerObjectBase();

    void requestAbort();
protected:
    //some WorkerObject basic parameters
    bool abortRequested();

public slots:
    virtual void process();

    signals:
           void workerFinished();   

private:
    QMutex abortMutex;
    bool abort = false;
};
```

**WorkerHandlerBase.cpp**

```
void WorkerObjectBase::requestAbort()
{
    abortMutex.lock();
    abort = true;
    abortMutex.unlock();
}

bool WorkerObjectBase::abortRequested()
{
    bool abortRequested;
    abortMutex.lock();
    abortRequested = abort;
    abortMutex.unlock();
    return abortRequested;
}
```

**WorkerObjectA.h**

```
class WorkerObjectA : public WorkerObjectBase {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    WorkerObjectA(QObject * parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~WorkerObjectA();

protected:
    //some WorkerObjectA parameters

public slots:
    void process();
};
```

**WorkerObjectA.cpp**

```
void WorkerObjectA::process()
{
    while(!abortRequested())
    {
        //do some stuff
    }
    emit workerFinished();
}
```

The problem is, when i use wait, it blocks the signal processing. workerFinished is not handled and QThread does not quit. But I still don't get why. When i create a new worker object, i move it to a different thread. When this thread is started, it runs its own QEventLoop as stated in QThread

**5.5 Documentation:**

> void QThread::run()
>
> The starting point for the thread. After calling start(), the newly
>   created thread calls this function. The default implementation simply
>   calls exec().

So even if my WorkerHandler thread is blocking because of calling wait, the QThread of the specific workerObject should still manage to get the workerFinished signal and call the quit slot. If i don't use wait at all, everything is fine. But when something unexpected happens in the worker object process method that keeps it from emitting workerFinished, i want to be able to kill the thread the hard way.

So, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `WorkerHandler::abortWorker` is executed in the same event loop as the `QThread::quit`. So the `WorkerHandler::abortWorker` is waiting, and `QThread::quit` slot invocation is still queued to the event loop.

Comment: Ok. I thought abortWorker is executed in EventLoop of WorkerHandler and `QThread::quit` in the the one of the WorkerObject. How I am supposed to use wait, when I can't use it this way in the creating thread?

Comment: The EventLoop of WorkerHandler is an overkill, because it's running just one `WorkerObjectBase::process` function. If you want to keep it anyway, try to replace the `workerThread->wait` with a `QTimer` that will in 10 seconds asynchronously check that the thread has finished, because otherwise if you've got 10 hung workers to stop - you'll wait for 100 seconds. Or, if you want to wait sequentially, call `QThread::quit` in `WorkerHandler::abortWorker` before `QThread::wait` (it won't interfere with WorkerObjectA::process, because the Loop can't quit without finishing executing current callback)

Comment: I used the `QThread::quit` solution for now. Actually the WorkerHandler does a lot more, like getting results from the WorkerObjects, storing them in an internal database and some other data model stuff. Maybe the EventLoop is still overkill, I don't know. Whatever, thanks for your answers.